# How to get text from inside span or outside at the same time with xpath?

Tags: python, list, xpath, scrapy

I have a problem with using xpath to get inconsistent price list

**Example**

```
<td><span="green">$33.99</span></td>
<td>Out of stock</td>
<td><span="green">$27.99</span></td>
<td><span="green">$35.00</span></td>
```

How to get the price inside span and Out of stock at the same time?
Because I get only $33.99 or anything that have span and text that is not inside span got skipped. And it ruined the ordering.

The failed attempt that I used w/ updated from @piratefache's solution (Scrapy)

```
product_prices_tds = response.xpath('//td/')
    product_prices = []

    for td in product_prices_tds:
        if td.xpath('//span'):
            product_prices = td.xpath('//span/text()').extract()
        else:
            product_prices = td.xpath('//text()').extract()

    for n in range(len(product_names)):
        items['price'] = product_prices[n]
        yield items
```

It's not working because product_prices doesn't get the right text it get from all over the place. Not just inside span or outside as I intended to.

**Update**
For the one who came later. I fixed my code Thanks to @piratefache's. Here's corrected snippet for who want to use later.

```
product_prices_tds = response.xpath('//td')
    product_prices = []

    for td in product_prices_tds:
        if td.xpath('span'):
            product_prices.append(td.xpath('span//text()').extract())
        else:
            product_prices.append(td.xpath('/text()').extract())

    for n in range(len(product_names)):
        items['price'] = product_prices[n]
        yield items
```

Comment: You're probably using BeautifulSoup library to get your html. What is your code so far?

Comment: First I used //td/span/text() to get this. But not get out of stock
Second I tried with //td/text() | /span/text() I got a better results but it's not unionize the result to one. It's just list outside span with \n thing. And next is get thing inside span is $33.99 for another array. Not join into one result.

Comment: Alright, Can you please edit your post and add your code? It will be easier to debug it.

Comment: updated code on the post.

Comment: I don't see any runnable Python code yet?

Comment: updated it again to be more proper and modified code from @piratefache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**See edit below with Scrapy**

Based on your html code, using BeautifulSoup library, you can get the information this way :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """<td><span="green">$33.99</span></td>
          <td>Out of stock</td>
            <td><span="green">$27.99</span></td>
            <td><span="green">$35.00</span></td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features="lxml")
tds = soup.body.findAll('td') # get all spans

for td in tds:

    # if attribute span exist
    if td.find('span'):
        print(td.find('span').text)
    # if not, just print inner text (here it's out of stock)
    else:
        print(td.text)
```

output :

```
$33.99
Out of stock
$27.99
$35.00
```

With Scrapy:

```py
import scrapy

page = """<td><span="green">$33.99</span></td>
          <td>Out of stock</td>
            <td><span="green">$27.99</span></td>
            <td><span="green">$35.00</span></td>"""

response = scrapy.Selector(text=page, type="html")
tds = response.xpath('//td')

for td in tds:

    # if attribute span exist
    if td.xpath('span'):
        print(td.xpath('span//text()')[0].extract())
    # if not, just print inner text (here it's out of stock)
    else:
        print(td.xpath('text()')[0].extract())
```

output :

```
$33.99
Out of stock
$27.99
$35.00
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not specific. But I use scrapy. bs4 cannot get data with js rendered.

Comment: Yes! I fixed my code with correct syntax like your suggestion and it's working. You are my lifesaver. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

XPath solution (from 2.0 upwards) (same logic as @piratefache posted before):

```
for $td in //td 
return 
if ($td[span]) 
then
$td/span/data() 
else 
$td/data()
```

Applied on

```
<root>
    <td>
        <span>$33.99</span>
    </td>
    <td>Out of stock</td>
    <td>
        <span>$27.99</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>$35.00</span>
    </td>
</root>
```

returns

```
 $33.99
 Out of stock
 $27.99
 $35.00
```

BTW: `<span="green">` is not valid XML. Probably an attribute @color or similar is missing (?)